# Typescript returning Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TimerHandler?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to update the count of number of message received by use on live server in angular 7 like we have in facebook and linkedin on main page and i have tried the following code:-

the code to fetch message:-

```
getMessageCount(rid:any)
    {
      return this.http.get<any>(this.apiUrl+'message/'+rid);
    }
on the main page we have the following code run like this :-
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
   userAuthenticated=false;
   private tmessage:any;
  constructor(private service:LoginService,private mService:MessagingService) {
    if(this.service.currentUserValue)
    {
      this.userAuthenticated=true;
      const id=this.service.currentUserValue.id;
      window.setInterval(this.getMessages(id),5);

    }
  }
}
```

upon sending the new message it should be updated without reloading the page ,can anybody tell me what i can do to achieve it ?

Answer (score 44):

You didn't provide `getMessages`, so I have to guess.

My guess is, `getMessages` is a void function, doing something, probably updating model/view and not returning anything, while the first parameter of `setTimeout` should be a function. Therefore, this

```
      window.setInterval(this.getMessages(id), 5);
```

should be

```
      window.setInterval(() => this.getMessages(id), 5);
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is `setInterval()` needs a function as the first argument(also called as a callback function). Then it executes that function after the set amount of time. And also not only run the function once as `setTimeout()` but regularly after the given interval of time. But you are not giving a function in your code

`window.setInterval(this.getMessages(id), 5);`

but just giving a value return by the function `getMessages(id)`.

So the correct way should be

```
window.setInterval(() => this.getMessages(id), 5);
```

which now gives a function that can be executed after the given amount of time.

And there is another method where you can call the function by `function.call()`.

```
window.setInterval(() => this.getMessages.call(this, id), 5)
```

`call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

Hope this will help you. (Please correct me if there is anything wrong. Thanks in Advance)